# How can I pass data in react native navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dom-events

Native navigation.

I want to "hi" data to Food Component from Main Component  through navigation.

This is my code:

```
const Main = ({navigation}) => {

     dispatch({
          type: COOK_UP_REQUEST,
     })
     navigation.navigate('Food' ,{hi:"hi"});
},[]);     


const Food = ({navigation}) => {

   console.log(hi);

     return (

     );
};
```

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a code example to send data from one screen to an other and how to get values in params in second screen.

**Screen 1**

```
const Main = ({ navigation }) => {
  const onButtonPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('', { hi: 'hi' }); // Passing Value
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={onButtonPress} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

**Screen 2**

```
const Food = ({ route }) => {
  const { hi } = route.params; // Receiving Value

  console.log('hi', hi);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{hi}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the error message is or what you are trying to achieve. But if trying to pass data on a button click whilst navigating to a new screen.

Try something like this on button press;

```
  onPress={() => navigate('Food', { hi: "hi"})}
```

That is considering that you have navigation setup correctly e.g. Stack Navigator, Stack Screen etc. in app.js/index.js